# Why do homotopy theorists care whether or not $BP$ is $E_\infty$?

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, homotopy-theory, stable-homotopy

I have often heard that it is not known whether or not the Brown-Peterson spectrum $BP$ is an $E_\infty$-ring spectrum. Though I see that this is a somewhat natural question to ask, I have often wondered what would the practical consequences of an answer to this question would be.

In particular, I am wondering what would a positive answer to this question mean for homotopy theory. Are there computations we would be able to do that we couldn't do before? What would be the take away if $BP$ did not admit an $E_\infty$-ring structure?

I would also appreciate any references on this problem. Thanks!

Comment: See the first page of Johnson-Noel's "For complex orientations preserving power operations, p-typicality is atypical", which has a brief paragraph about this.

Comment: Since this question was asked,  [Tyler Lawson has shown that](http://www-users.math.umn.edu/~tlawson/papers/secondary.pdf) at $p = 2$, $\mathit{BP}$ is not an $E_n$ algebra for $n\ge 12$, thus providing a negative answer to this conjecture at 2.

Comment: Since Arun's comment, [Andrew Senger has shown](https://arxiv.org/abs/1710.09822) $BP$ is not $\mathbb{E}_{2(p^2+2)}$ for odd primes, providing a negative answer in general.

Answer (score 23):

I suppose I should try to answer since the question of whether or not $BP$ is an $E_{\infty}$ ring spectrum
was Problem 1 of "Problems in infinite loop space theory'', http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~may/PAPERS/16.pdf,
written in 1974, two years after $E_{\infty}$ ring spectra were first defined.   At the time, we were hoping for some good
way of starting from the relevant group law and manufacturing $BP$ from it.  The example "in nature'' that led to
the definition of $E_{\infty}$ ring spectra was $MU$, so it was impossible not to be intrigued by the question.
Some things proven since with $MU$ might be streamlined if we could start with $BP$, such as the construction
of Morava $K$-theory.   However, Basterra and Mandell proved that $BP$ is an $E_4$-spectrum, compatibly with $MU$, which is enough for such
applications.   I'm still intrigued by the question, although I admit to having no applications in mind.

Comment: Just a personal curiosity, but do you know of any application that requires $BP$ to be more than $E_1$?

Comment: Well certainly one wants the category of $BP$-modules to be symmetric monoidal under the smash product, which won't come from $E_1$, and one wants to know how which Dyer-Lashof operations are preserved from $MU$ (not all, of course).

Comment: @PeterMay, what is the general belief amongst homotopy theorists regarding an answer to this question? Is there evidence pointing one way or the other?

Comment: I doubt there is a consensus.  It is $E_4$ compatibly with $MU$, but if it is $E_{\infty}$, then it only is so incompatibly with $MU$.   I have no strong feeling, but I would hazard a guess that it is not $E_{\infty}$.

Comment: It is worth pointing out that if $BP$ is $E_{\infty}$ then Andy Baker has constructed it (if I recall correctly). https://arxiv.org/abs/1204.4878

Also, @PeterMay, is this https://arxiv.org/pdf/1310.3336v1.pdf the reference you had in mind with your above comment about the Quillen idempotent being $E_4$? I don't recall them getting more than $E_3$, but maybe you mean a different paper.

Comment: Sean, I said Basterra and Mandell. The paper is ``The multiplication on $BP$" and the abstract reads in full: ``$BP$ is an $E_4$ ring spectrum. The $E_4$ structure is unique up to automorphism

Comment: I see my confusion!! The construction of Basterra-Mandell is *some* idempotent as opposed to the Quillen idempotent. Thanks for pointing this out.